# How to fix Scaffold-DbContext command Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: visual-studio

I am executing the PM> Scaffold-DbContext .... command, however the Login failed error is displayed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

I refer to the Scaffolding Command -
Scaffold-DbContext "Server =. \ SQLExpress; Database = xxxx; Trusted_Connection = True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

It works fine under Local, however when I connect to the database Server the Login failed error.

The command when connecting to my database server:
Scaffold-DbContext "Server = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \ Server Name, Port; Database = xxx; User ID = xx; Password = ***; Trusted_Connection = True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

---- TCP / IP Port enabled
---- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: IP Server

Give me the solution! Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. My password contained the character $ and this needs to be escaped out by using apostrophe before the $

Comment: Tks for reply, I figured out my problem. Set Trusted_Connection = False;"